# supporting multiple screen sizes and orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Please help me... I create my first project in android and no any experience in android UI. ![enter image description here][1]

res/layout/main.xml.

res/layout-land/main.xml

res/layout-large/main.xml

res/layout-large-land/main.xml

res/layout-xlarge/main.xml

res/layout-xlarge-land/main.xml

res/layout-sw600dp/main.xml

res/layout-sw600dp-land/main.xml

res/layout-sw720dp/main.xml

res/layout-sw720dp-land/main.xml

> this folder's layout structure is correct for handling every screen
>   size?
>
> and android version <3.2 and >3.2 supports for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your first project in android, focus on building your initial UI without worrying about alternate adaptations for other devices. Many times 1-2 layouts is enough (portrait/landscape) - If you stick to DP/SP units.

Once your initial UI is in place, test different devices in the emulator to see if you need to create any adaptations.

Comment: this folder structure is not valid in android? or I use values dimension for every view?

Comment: It's valid, it's just excessive.

Answer (score 0):

Give a good idea about your question while asking .

As a beginner you can just use res/layout and if u want to use in landscape mode use res/landscape mode.

Try to Start with these two . You Will Need Other Options Later .

Also Use sp , dp for size like font size or height .

Comment: this Structure is not valid??

Comment: That 's valid .You can use it but just one or two r sufficient i think as a beginner .